# Queues in C - Basic Input Output in Main Method

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I am implenting a queue data structure in C. In the main method, it asks the user for some data (using scanf) that will be used to be put into a node in the queue.(CASE 2). Before it enqueues it, it displays that same information to the user using printf. This should be straightforward however when it tries to display the rowNumber, it is a completely different number. And as for the passengerName, it crashes with a segmentation fault(core dumped).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Structure definitions
// self-referential structure
struct queueNode {
    int rowNumber;
    char seat;
    char* passengerName;
    struct queueNode* nextPtr;// queueNode pointer
};                             // end structure queueNode

typedef struct queueNode QueueNode;
typedef QueueNode* QueueNodePtr;

//prototypes
void printQueue(QueueNodePtr currentPtr);
int isEmpty(QueueNodePtr headPtr);
char dequeue(QueueNodePtr* headPtr, QueueNodePtr* tailPtr);
void enqueue(QueueNodePtr* headPtr, QueueNodePtr* tailPtr, int rowNum, char seatLetter, char* passengersName);
void instructions(void);
void front(QueueNodePtr currentPtr);

int main(void)
{
    QueueNodePtr queuePtr = NULL;
    QueueNodePtr tailPtr = NULL;
    int rowNumber;
    char seat;
    char passengerName;
    int choice;
    printf("Enter choice: \n1 To show the passenger most recently added to the train. \n2 To add a passenger to the train. \n3 To "
           "remove the most recently added  passenger in the train. \n4 To print a list of all train passengers. \n5 To exit this program.\n\nYour choice:");
    //fgets(choice,1,stdin); 
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    while(choice != 5) {

    switch(choice) {

    case 1: // show first passenger in the queue
        if (!isEmpty(queuePtr)){
        front(queuePtr);
        }
        else{
        printf("The queue is empty.\n");
        }       
        break;
    case 2: // enqueue a passenger on the queue

        printf("\nEnter a row number: ");
        scanf("%d", &rowNumber);
        //fgets(rowNumber,2,stdin);

        printf("\nEnter a seat letter: ");
        scanf("%c", &seat);
        scanf("%c", &seat);
        //fgets(seat,1,stdin);

        printf("\nEnter a name for the passenger: ");
        scanf("%s", &passengerName);
        //fgets(passengerName,500,stdin);

        printf("\n\nEntered: \n");
        printf("%d", rowNumber);
        printf("\n");
        printf("%c", seat);
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s", passengerName);
        printf("\n\n");


        enqueue(queuePtr,tailPtr,rowNumber,seat,passengerName);


        break;

    case 3: // dequeue a passenger on the stack



        printf("dequeue");

        printf("\n\n^ Most Recently Added passenger is deleted\n\n");

        break;

    case 4: // print the stack

        printf("printstack");
        break;

    case 5: // exit the program

        break;

    default:

        printf("Invalid choice.\n\n");
        break;
    }
      printf("Enter choice: \n1 To show the passenger most recently added to the train. \n2 To add a passenger to the train. \n3 To "
           "remove the most recently added  passenger in the train. \n4 To print a list of all train passengers. \n5 To exit this program.\n\nYour choice:");
    //fgets(choice,1,stdin); 
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    printf("\n\nEnd of run.\n");

    return 0;
}//end main


// insert a node in at queue tail
void enqueue(QueueNodePtr* headPtr, QueueNodePtr* tailPtr, int rowNum, char seatLetter, char* passengersName)
{
    QueueNodePtr newPtr; // pointer to new node

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));

    if(newPtr != NULL) { // is space available
    newPtr->rowNumber = rowNum;
        newPtr->seat = seatLetter;
        newPtr->passengerName = strdup(passengersName);
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

    // if empty, insert node at head
    if(isEmpty(*headPtr)) {
        *headPtr = newPtr;
    } // end if
    else {
        (*tailPtr)->nextPtr = newPtr;

    } // end else

    *tailPtr = newPtr;
    } // end if
    else {
    printf("Not inserted. No memory available.\n");
    } // end else
} // end function enqueue

// remove node from queue head
/*char dequeue(QueueNodePtr* headPtr, QueueNodePtr* tailPtr)
{
    char value;           // node value
    QueueNodePtr tempPtr; // temporary node pointer

    value = (*headPtr)->data;
    tempPtr = *headPtr;
    *headPtr = (*headPtr)->nextPtr;

    // if queue is empty
    if(*headPtr == NULL) {
    *tailPtr = NULL;
    } // end if

    free(tempPtr);
    return value;
} */// end function dequeue

// return 1 if the queue is empty, 0 otherwise
int isEmpty(QueueNodePtr headPtr)
{
    return headPtr == NULL;
} // end function isEmpty

// print the queue
/*void printQueue(QueueNodePtr currentPtr)
{
    // if queue is empty
    if(currentPtr == NULL) {
    puts("Queue is empty.\n");
    } // end if
    else {
    puts("The queue is:");

    // while not end of queue
    while(currentPtr != NULL) {

        printf("%c --> ", currentPtr->data);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    } // end while

    puts("NULL\n");
    } // end else
} */// end function printQueue

//print first passenger in queue
void front(QueueNodePtr currentPtr)
{
    printf("\n\nThe passenger at the beginning of the queue is:\n\n");

    printf("\n%d ", currentPtr->rowNumber);
    printf("\n%c ", currentPtr->seat);
    printf("\n%s  ", currentPtr->passengerName);
    printf("\n\n");
}//end function front
```

Comment: Just one of the problems I see at the first glance: `passengerName` is a single character. You are trying to read a string into it.

Comment: Just dumping a bunch of code on us with a brief description of the problem isn't very helpful to you or to us. First, get rid of the commented-out code. Second, narrow the problem down to something brief that we can easily examine. It would help you to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)